# How to attach extra volume on Centos7 server

Tags: server, centos7, volume, mount

I have created additional volume on my server.

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        19G  3.4G   15G  19% /
devtmpfs        874M     0  874M   0% /dev
tmpfs           896M     0  896M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           896M   17M  879M   2% /run
tmpfs           896M     0  896M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           180M     0  180M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sdb         25G   44M   24G   1% /mnt/HC_Volume_1788024`

How can I attach /dev/sdb either to the whole server (I mean merge it with "/dev/sda1") or assign it to specific directory on server "/var/lib" without overwriting current /var/lib...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your will not be able to "merge" as you are using standard sdX devices and not using something like LVM for file systems.
As root, you can manually run:
    `mount /dev/sdb /var/lib/`

The original content of /var/lib will still be there (taking up space on your / filesystem)
To make permanent, (carefully) edit your /etc/fstab and add a line like:

```
/dev/sdb           /var/lib                   FILESYSTEM_OF_YOUR_SDB_DISK     defaults        0 0
```

You will need to replace "FILESYSTEM_OF_YOUR_SDB_DISK" with the correct filesystem type ("df -T", "blkid" or "lsblk -f" will show the type)

You should test the "correctness" of your /etc/fstab by first:
    `umount /var/lib` (if you previously mounted)
Then run:
    `mount -a` then
    `df -T`
and you should see the mount point corrected and the "mount -a" should have not produced any error.